# Quarkus jvm deploy remote docker fail

Tags: docker, quarkus

I deploy my quarkus app with dockerfile to remote docker in my windows computer, but it fails. How should I fix it?

I package my quarkus app successed.
[I package it used maven jvm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TFqS.png)

This is my IDEA docker image setting
[docker image setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgGve.png)

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.11
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'


# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV AB_JOLOKIA_OFF=""
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"
```

I get fail reason:

```
Error response from daemon: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat target/quarkus-app/lib/: file does not exist
Failed to deploy 'bigquarkus Dockerfile: src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream
```

Comment: What does the output of `mvn package` look like on the file system?

Comment: It may sound silly but did you check .dockerignore for excluded 'target/quarkus-app/lib/' ?

Comment: the output of mvn package is show BUILD SUCCESS. I have delete .dockerignore so I think it hasn't effection.

Answer (score 0):

I find I mistake my build context folder, so the maven can not find the .dockerignore file. When I set my context folder to . , I can build and push my docker image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).